# Why parsing this JSON throwing an error?

Tags: java

I am trying to parse this JSONObject

```
{
    "query": {
        "yahoo:count": 1,
        "results": {
            "rate": {
                "Name": "USD/INR",
                "id": "USDINR",
                "Time": "12:19pm",
                "Date": "10/31/2015",
                "Bid": 65.405,
                "Ask": 65.43,
                "Rate": 65.405
            }
        },
        "yahoo:created": "2015-11-01T02:16:56Z",
        "yahoo:lang": "en-US",
        "xmlns:yahoo": "http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    }
}
```

This is my program

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, JSONException {

        String json = "{\"query\":{\"yahoo:count\":1,\"results\":{\"rate\":{\"Name\":\"USD/INR\",\"id\":\"USDINR\",\"Time\":\"12:19pm\",\"Date\":\"10/31/2015\",\"Bid\":65.405,\"Ask\":65.43,\"Rate\":65.405}},\"yahoo:created\":\"2015-11-01T02:16:56Z\",\"yahoo:lang\":\"en-US\",\"xmlns:yahoo\":\"http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng\"}}";

        JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject(json);

        String Rate = json_obj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results")
                .getJSONObject("rate").getString("Rate");

        System.out.println(Rate);

    }

}

Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["Rate"] not a string.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:644)
    at Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this ??

Comment: JSONObject["Rate"] not a string. , pasted the exception stack trace in question .

Answer (score 0):

Its strict about its types, `getString("Rate")` is not a string its a number. To get the number value use `getDouble("rate")`. You can also use the type safe get of `get("rate")` which should return a `Double` then call `toString()` on it.

Comment: Thank you so much , does all the JSON Parsers work this way or is there any parsing framework which can manage these things ??

Comment: @Kiran Every JSON framework must have a way to handle the multiple types of values JSON provides. For instance you can just use `set(value)` for everything because there are multiple ways to represent a value in JSON. For instance with numbers `{ value : "1.5" }` is not the same as `{ value : 1.5 }`.  The json.org implementation handles this just as well as anyone. If you dont want to deal with the types just use the general `get(value)` and deal with object type primitives. Is there some way of accessing the data which you dont like with this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the stack trace obvious? Rate is not a string, but an integer. You should use `getInt` or `getNumber` or whatever is called in Java, instead of `getString`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
.getDouble("Rate")
```

instead of

```
.getString("Rate")
```

rate is double not string